# Delphi - accessing a hint window's canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-2007, hint

Is there a succinct way of accessing the canvas of a hint window?  I don't want to draw anything on the canvas - I will just assign to the component's `Hint` property -  but I do want to find out the width of text that Windows would render using whatever font is being used for the hint window text.

*** The Reason ***

I'm trying to construct hint windows with tabbed columns in them, e.g.

```
SomeControl.Hint := 
  'Item 1:       ' + #9 + 'Tom' + #13 +
  'Item 2:       ' + #9 + 'Dick' + #13 +
  'Another Item: ' + #9 + 'Harry' + #13 ;
```

and I want the names to all tab under one another.  The example shown above will tab correctly only if the hint font is mono-spaced.  I can achieve it with a given proportional font by trial and error by padding the lines with the right number of spaces, but I want it to work for any font.  Most of the examples I have seen seem to be for changing the appearance of the hint window - all I want to do is be able to call `Canvas.TextWidth` so I can calculate what padding I need to add to "push" the line over the next tab stop.

*** UPDATE ***

I was labouring under a misapprehension - I was assuming that the hint control respected the tab character but in fact it seems to ignore it.  The TLabel component on the other hand does respect the tab character - it seems to move to the next multiple of 10 or so space widths.

Comment: Plus one for the Tom Dick and Harry reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

1. There is `Screen.HintFont` property than you can assign to any canvas you want and get your hint text dimensions.
2. There is global `HintWindowClass` Delphi application uses to create hint windows and you can create your own and use its canvas to do text measuring.

You can use it like this:

```
var
  HintCtrl: THintWindow;

  HintCtrl := HintWindowClass.Create(nil);
  HintCtrl.Canvas.TextWidth('abc');
  ...
```

Comment: First class answer.  Many thanks.  Just a question:  why do you create the variable `HintCtrl` with `HintCtrl := HintWindowClass.Create(nil);` - why not `HintCtrl := THintWindow.Create(nil);` ?

Comment: You can use `THintWindow` too, but since `HintWindowClass` is used for customizing hint windows, I prefer to use more generic solution. Of course, if there is custom behavior implemented, then your `HintCtrl` would have to be created after `HintWindowClass` is assigned with another value.